# Building a Jpeg Slideshow in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I need to build Java Swing Desktop Application in which JPEGs from a particular folder are picked up and then are displayed in a blur fashioned Slideshow.

Please help!!

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a correct question to ask on stackoverflow.
You need to be more specific. What issues do you face while implementing this, etc.

Anyway, here is some tip:
To learn how to use fullscreen mode, read the following guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html

Comment: +1 now you can posting a comments eveywhere

Comment: Yeah, that's what I needed.
Thank you, mKorbel